# Subscribe onComplete never completes with flatMap

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

I'm using `Angular 6` with `RxJS 6.2.2` and `RxJS Compact 6.2.2`.

I have a code to call my api service to load some records, which is:

```
this.route.params
  .flatMap((params: Params) => {
    if (!params['id']) {
      return Observable.throwError('Id is not specified.');
    }

    this.itemId = params['id'];
    this.isEditMode = true;
    this.loadCategoryGroupCondition = new LoadCategoryGroupViewModel();
    this.loadCategoryGroupCondition.id = [this.itemId];
    this.loadCategoryGroupCondition.pagination = new Pagination();

    return this.categoryGroupService
      .loadCategoryGroup(this.loadCategoryGroupCondition);
  })
  .subscribe(
    (loadCategoryGroupResult: SearchResult<CategoryGroup>) => {
      console.log(loadCategoryGroupResult);
    },
    () => {},
    () => {
      console.log('Completed')
    });
```

The code above can print a list of my items returned from my api service. That means onSuccess has been called.

But the complete method is fired.
What is wrong with my code ?

Thank you,

Comment: Why would it complete?

Comment: Your title says "never completes" but in your question you say "but the complete method is fired', so what do you expect and what is happening?

Comment: Btw `Observable.throwError` looks strange, in previous rxjs it was `Observable.throw` and in v6 its just `throwError`...

Comment: @MartinAdámek, I would 2 messages to be displayed:
- The first one should be: console.log(loadCategoryGroupResult);
- The second one should be: console.log('Completed')

My actual case is :
- console.log(loadCategoryGroupResult) is called.
-  console.log('Completed') isn't

Comment: That's because `this.route.params` never completes. Only your api call that is merged to the chain. If you want complete to be called you need to complete all source Observables.

Comment: @martin, do you have any solution for this ?
I've tried `switchMap` but it doesn't work. I just want to do some actions when my api load is done. Event the loading has error or not.

Comment: use  `this.route.params.take(1).flatMap(...`

Comment: @ggradnig, thank you, I've tried your solution and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed, the `flatMap` operator does itself not complete its source observable. You are using `this.route.params` as your source observable, which is long-lived - it never completes by itself.

To get a `complete` notification you can use an operator such as `take`. It will re-emit the number of items you pass as a parameter and complete afterwards. For example, if you just want to receive the current route and are not interested in further notifications of your source observable, use `take(1)`, like:

```
this.route.params
  .take(1)
  .flatMap((params: Params) => {
```

Also, note that the recommeded way for doing this in RxJS 6+ is using pipeable operators. This would look like so:

```
this.route.params.pipe(
  first(),
  mergeMap((params: Params) => {
  ...
})
```

I also replaced the operators with the newer recommended variants.

Comment: I don't know what is the use case for the mentioned code, but if params does not emit any value (because the route does not contain), then using first (instead of take(1)) will emit an error. Correct me if I am wrong.